# JPA Auditing happens at an unexpected time

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Given**

I am using the @EnableJpaAuditing of Spring to add auditing information to my entities. My JPA auditing configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Slf4j
public class JpaAuditingConfiguration {

@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
    return
        () -> {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {

            // there must always be an authentication context
            // return null here, which will later cause a constraint violation exception when trying to store into
            // the DB
            return null;
        } else {
            final String userName = authentication.getName();
            log.trace("Found Auditor: {}", userName);
            return userName;
        }
    };
}
```

}

My entities looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mfe", name = "my_first_entity")
@ToString(exclude = {"mySecondEntities"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@EntityListeners({ BusinessKeyEntityListener.class })
public class MyFirstEntity extends AbstractModifiable {
    // here are some properties
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myFirstEntity", fetch =   FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<MySecondEntity> mySecondEnttities;
}
```

The AbstractModifiable super class looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class })
public abstract class AbstractModifiable {
    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant created;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModified;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
}
```

The name of the table of the first entity is:

mfe.**my_first_entity**

The name of the table of the second entity is:

mse.**my_second_entity**

1)

**When** using the entityManager to persist and update my entity my_first_entity:

```
myFirstEntityRepository.save(myFirstEntity);
```

**Then** the auditing happens in the expected way and the attributes for the table my_first_entity in my database like "last_modified" is changed.

2)

**When** using a manual script to update the table my_first_entity where the entityManager is not used.

**Then** there is no auditing information like "last_modified" is added to the table my_first_entity.

3)

**When** using a manual script to update the table my_first_entity where the entityManager is not used.

**And** afterwards I use the JPA entityManager to persist a different entity:

```
    @Transactional
    public void createSnapshotEvents(String eventType, String flowId) {
    Stream snapshotItemsStream = this.tarbelaSnapshotProvider.getSnapshot(eventType);
    Iterators.partition(snapshotItemsStream.iterator(), this.tarbelaProperties.getSnapshotBatchSize().intValue()).forEachRemaining((batch) -> {
        List events = (List)batch.stream().map((item) -> {
            return this.eventLogMapper.createEventLog(EventDataOperation.SNAPSHOT, item, flowId);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.eventLogRepository.save(events);
    });
    this.eventLogRepository.flush();
}
```

**Then** there is auditing information added to the table my_first_entity, which is what I don't expect.

**What I expect is** that my entity my_first_entity is not touched and the auditing doesn't happen if I do a manual modification to my tables.

Comment: Your question is confusing (use real names instead of made up names). Assuming `Eve` is also mapped to the table `Bob` then of course there will be audit logging added.

Comment: You are right. I added that the entities are mapped to the table with the same name. Bob is mapped to table Bob and Eve to table Eve.

Comment: It still is confusing, just use proper names. If there is a relation between eve and bob then there is data written. However you only mention some vague names and pseudo entities. Show some (anonymized) code with relations etc.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope it helps now.